# Deleted recovery partition from Acer Aspire Switch 10

Tags: acer-aspire, partition-recovery

I've done something wrong and deleted the recovery partition on my Acer Switch 10. I've done a lot of searches on google and a lot of tries, but I still can't boot the os. The problem is that at the boot an error 0x0000225 is displayed. At the moment I can boot a windows 8.1 installation from usb pen drive. All repairs tools don't work. I've tried to install windows 8.1, but during the installation a message appears: "windows cannot install reuquired files. Make sure all files required for installation are available, and restart the installation. I've created the bootable pen drive using rufus.

Do you know something I can do to revive my Acer?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with: Do you know something I can do to revive my Acer? Do you want to get your recovery partion back or is it just enought if you can boot and run your windwos agian on your computer?

Comment: http://www.eightforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/50910-error-0x0000225.html

Comment: @ Stackcraft_noob It is just enough if I can boot and run windows.
@ DavidPostill Yes. I've read it. My next step it's call Acer. In the meanwhile I'm searching for some alternative solution.

Thanks all for reply

Comment: See if this helps...https://itsolutionsblog.net/solution-to-your-pc-needs-to-be-repaired/

Comment: Thanks for reply. Still not working. But I can provide further info. If I press f8 in the failure screen (when 0x0000225 error is displayed) I see "The operating system couldn't be loaded because the HAL is missing or contains errors. File: \windows\system32\halmcpi.dll"

Comment: You need to more precise, IF partitions were deleted and you need them back with data back you will have to be very careful. For starters update OP with screenshot of Disk Management, IGNORE any prompts to initialize etc..

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur if Windows Boot files are corrupted. I would suggest you to try these steps and check if it helps.

Method 1:
Normally, if you are unable to boot the Windows 8.1 to its Start Screen, the Automatic Repair will check for the errors which is preventing Windows from booting up and will fix it. If this does not happen, then when you may need to run the Automatic Repair by booting the computer to Windows 8.1 installation/recovery disc and then it will fix the issue if the issue with any startup files required for Windows 8.1 to boot up.
Boot the computer from the disc and then try the following method to perform an Automatic Repair of Windows 8.1.

Contact the computer manufacturer to know on how to change the boot order of the computer. You will have to change the boot device to CD/DVD drive and then boot from the Windows 8.1 installation disk.
In the “Windows Setup” dialog box that appears, set the Time and currency format, Keyboard or input method and the language to install and then click “Next”.
Click on “Repair your computer” from the lower left corner.
From the “Choose an option screen”, click on “Troubleshoot”.
Click “Advanced Options” in the “Troubleshoot” screen.
In the “Advanced Options” screen, click “Automatic Repair”.
Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the Automatic Repair. Check if you can boot to desktop.

Method 2:
If issue persists, run these commands in command prompt and check if it helps. Boot your computer from disk then go to Windows Setup>Repair your computer>Trouble Shoot > Advanced Options > Command Prompt.

```
bootrec /scanos
bootrec /rebuildbcd
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

Reboot.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've tried both methods, but it still isn't working. I've contacted Acer care and they told me the only one solution is reinstall the os with a recovery cd/dvd that they'll send to me. This is an expensive solution (50€ + taxes, for me in Italy is 61€), but at the end I'm going to buy this recovery kit.